# Refresh user's permissions after removed from a role

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a project where I can assign users to roles. My problem is that when I remove a user from a role, the user will be able to access the resources that he is no loger supposed to see. The only way to refresh his permissions is when he log off and login again.

This is a problem because when I want to stop a user from accessing sensitive data, I can not do it because the framework has cached his permissions.

The permissions will not be updated even if I restart the application. Is there a way to clear a users cached permissions when I remove him from a role or when I add him in a role?

Comment: Perhaps this is what you're looking for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?tabs=aspnetcore2x#reacting-to-back-end-changes

Comment: This is the solution for my problem but it is going to be triggered on every request which is not something nice for the performance of the application.

Comment: Yes, I did notice that. You may be able to optimize it by only checking on certain paths and there may be ways to cache it, making it less expensive. On the other hand, it is the resource you want to protect. So why not move the authorization to the resource: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: What authentication provider are you using?

Comment: I use the Default Token Provider.  `.AddDefaultTokenProviders()`